# .each function skips hidden element and using multiple selectors in onchange funtion

Tags: jquery, html

```js
    $('#step1 input').change(function(){
       $('#step1 input').each(function(){
          console.log($(this).val());
       });
    });
    
    $('#step2 input').change(function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step1">
       Father's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       <input name="hiddenelement" type="text" hidden="hidden" value="This is Father's name" />
       <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
    </div>
    <div id="step2">
       Mother's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
    </div>
```

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="step1">
   Father's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <input name="hiddenelement" type="text" hidden="hidden" value="This is Father's name" />
   <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
</div>
<div id="step2">
   Mother's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
</div>
```

Using jquery I'm trying to get the name of both father and mother by the following code:

```
$('#step1 input').change(function(){
   $('#step1 input').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
   });
});

$('#step2 input').change(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

But when I give input as:
Father's name as Father and Mother's name as Mother,
I get the output as:

```
Father
Father
Mother
Mother
```

I have two doubts here. First, why is hidden element skipped and Second, why does changing one div reflect in giving output for both divs.
Can I please know where I am going wrong.
Would be of great help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. Can you link a a codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#step1 input').change(function(){
   $('#step1 input').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
   });
});

$('#step2 input').change(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step1">
   Father's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <input name="hiddenelement" type="text" hidden="hidden" value="This is Father's name" />
   <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
</div>
<div id="step2">
   Mother's Details: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <input name="First Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your input... You are right after I did a hard refresh it is giving the expected output, I don't realise what went wrong then, that it gave me this output.can you help me understand this behaviour as this has not happened for the first time....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe your `hidden` input is not coded correctly?  I always thought they were supposed to be set to `type="hidden"`, like `<input name="hiddenelement" type="hidden" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#step1 input').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
});
```